# Syntaxis variable environment ubuntu, bitnami

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, environment-variables, bitnami

Please help!!

I 'm using bitnami , based on Ubuntu , and I would like to know what the syntax and routes to add environment variables and use them in node.js

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami developer here.

If you deploy a Nodejs stack in the cloud you won't need to change the environment variables to use the components that are included in the installation. You will use the Nodejs binaries installed by Bitnami if you try to run the `node` command.

If you used a native installer, you'll need to load the environment of the installation. You will load the Bitnami console running the following command:

`installdir/use_nodejs`

You will learn more about the Bitnami console [here](https://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/BitNami_console).

Regards,
Jota